# Can there be a language not Context free but still PDA acceptable?

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

Let the input alphabet be $Σ = \{1,x,=\}$
Let the stack alphabet be $\tau = \{1,\$\}$ where $\$$ is the initial stack symbol.

Let,
$q_0$ be the initial state of the PDA,
$q_f$ be the final state of PDA,
I can define a transition function for PDA like this.

$(q_0,1,\$)\rightarrow(\$1,q_1)$
$(q_1,1,1)\rightarrow(1,q_1)$
$(q_1,x,1)\rightarrow(1,q_2)$
$(q_2,1,1)\rightarrow(1,q_2)$
$(q_2,=,1)\rightarrow(1,q_3)$
$(q_3,1,1)\rightarrow(\epsilon,q_3)$
$(q_3,\epsilon,\$)\rightarrow(\$,q_f)$

Now the PDA can recognize language $L = \{1^m x 1^n = 1^{mn}\}$
But According to https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1142/lectures/18/Small18.pdf Slide 24 this language is not Context Free.

Assume that I am quite beginner in TOC.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Automata, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton#PDA_and_context-free_languages

Comment: The set of context free languages include exactly those accepted by a PDA.

Comment: The problem here is that your PDA doesn't recognize $L$ but rather $\{1^mx1^n=1^{m+n}\}$.

Comment: @RickDecker Make an answer?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Nah. Too small to rate as an answer. Feel free, though.

Answer (score 1):

It is proven in your nearby language theory textbook (like Hopcroft, Motwani, Ullman ["Introduction to automata theory, languages, and computation"](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Hopcroft-Introduction-to-Automata-Theory-Languages-and-Computation-3rd-Edition/PGM64331.html) (3rd edition, Pearson) that the languages accepted by (nondeterministic) PDAs are exactly the context free languages (generated by context free grammars).